# Is it possible to know if a document is opened/viewed by user in xamarin android app?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, document

I need to check if a document (pdf,xls,docx,ppt..etc) is viewed by user or not. In some user's devices there are no apps to open some document types. In such cases I need to know that the document is not opened/viewed by user.

This is an android app developed using xamarin forms. Used below code to open document. This is working fine if there is an app to open respective document. But, if there are no apps to open the document it shows blank activity with the title "Choose an Application:"

```
    ...other code here...

  var chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Choose an Application:");
                activity.StartActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  check it by the Android file `MIME type`.Refer the following code

```
Dictionary<string, string> matchArray = new Dictionary<string, string>();

matchArray.Add(".3gp", "video/3gpp");
matchArray.Add(".apk", "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
matchArray.Add(".doc", "application/msword");
matchArray.Add(".gif", "image/gif");
matchArray.Add(".wps", "application/vnd.ms-works");
matchArray.Add(".pdf", "application/pdf");
matchArray.Add(".ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
matchArray.Add(".png", "image/png");
//... 

public void OpenFileByPath(Context context, string path)
{
  if (context == null || path == null)
    return;

  string type = "";
  foreach (string key in matchArray.Keys)
   {

     if (path.Contains(key))
       {
          type = matchArray[key];
          break;
       }
    }

  if (type == "")
    {
       //there is no app can open the file ,do some you want 
    }
  else
    {
       // open your file 
    }
}
```

You can add more key-values about MIME type by searching  from the  internet

Comment: I don't think this sol works for my scenario. Ex: In my app if there is a ".doc" file and user is trying to open it and there is no app installed on user's phone to open the file, then the file is not opened however the above code gives me the valid type value as the document path will have the key. Please let me know if I misunderstood anything here!. I need to know if the file can be opened on user's phone or not.

Comment: if (type == "") means there is no app on user's device can open the file

Comment: Sorry I am not getting your point here. 
We are only adding the types to matchArrasy so for example we added .doc like matchArray.Add(".doc", "application/msword"); so the line matchArray[key]; always return return a value. 
Where are we checking if some app is available to open our document on user's device?.